# Downhill bike build

Tags: downhill

What frame should I choose for free-ride / downhill between `Kona Stinky` and `Specialised Big Hit`?

I am a hobbyist downhill-er / free rider with average height 1.68 meters and 67 kg. 
I am asking your opinion about the cyclic of the bikes and rider stories about usability.